# Demora ao executar comandos SQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema onde trabalho com um `db` online hospedado em JustHost.com.
Sofro com a demora nas execuçoes dos comandos, mas nem sempre essas demoras existem, as vezes um comando leva menos de 1s e outra hora este mesmo comando leva cerca de 10s.

fiz um teste trabalhando com o `db` em LocalHost e corre tranquilo, sem demoras !

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de saber se é a velocidade da minha internet em particular ou é a transferencia de dados oferecida pelo servidor onde meu `db` está (JustHost.com).

E se alguém recomenda um Host para hospedar `db` melhor e mais rápido !

Comment: Tem certeza que não há nenhum erro no seu script? 10s para uma consulta é muito tempo, que tipo de hospedagem é a sua?

Comment: Pois é Leo, muito tempo! Mas como eu disse, as vezes essas demoras não acontecem, levando isso em consideração, deduzo que é a internet (minha ou da hospedagem que uso) que oscila na velocidade, não consigo achar onde vejo as configuraçoes da hospedagem, a empresa em que trabalho usa o justhost.com para hospedar os sites dela, daí uso essa mesma hospedagem pra criar e suar os `db` @LeoLetto

Comment: Nas informações de conta é pra ter o tipo de hospedagem muito estranho essa demora as vezes